# Graph of driver's times in karting races

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, timing

I'm working on a web and I'm having trouble graphing the following I have a dataset like this:

```
[{'Driver': 'JAN', 'LapTime': 97379}, {'Driver': 'PED', 'LapTime': 93996}, etc.... ]
```

*LapTime in Milliseconds

I've been trying to make them with chart js but I can't figure out how to work with the timings

I would like to have something of this style:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Fs1.png)

Comment: That honestly seems like something you would learn how to do if you just read the documentation and look at examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chart.js. You sort it and display it like this for example:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');



let sorted = [{'Driver': 'JAN', 'LapTime': 97379}, {'Driver': 'PED', 'LapTime': 93996}].sort((a,b) => a.LapTime - b.LapTime)


  new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: sorted.map(s => s.Driver),
      datasets: [{
         label: "Seconds",
         data: sorted.map(s => s.LapTime / 1000),
         borderWidth: 1
      }],
    },
    options: {
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```